# Compare values from two different tables, if equal then display

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a variable called $row['mykey'] that was genterated from a query on table one, I have echoed 
it to my page and it does display the value I'm looking for.  Now I need to use this varible to set my new query 
on table two, to only display results if it matches contractor_lock from table two. $stmt1 one works fine to display the entire table, but I want to use $stmt2 but get no data results.  Thanks for any help!

```
try {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


 $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT client_id, companyname, contact, contractor_lock FROM table_two");


 $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT client_id, companyname, contact, contractor_lock FROM table two WHERE contractor_lock = $row['mykey']"); 

 $stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
 foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
     echo $v;
 }
 }

catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
 $conn = null;
 }
```

Comment: why are you running two queries? you could do a single JOINed query, since your two tables obviously have a field that shares common data values.

Comment: new at this, and have never used join.  this was just the logic that was in my head.  I have so much to learn

Comment: researching for the last four hours, and came to my dead end.  It seem like it should be so simple!

Comment: Tables from statement1 and 2 are the same? If so u miss _ in table name in second statement, table_two ! table two

Comment: by the way, the variables i'm trying to compare have different names in their respective tables.  don't know if that makes a difference or not when using join

Comment: `select * from t1 inner join t2 on t1.contractor_lock = t2.contractor_lock where t1.contractor_lock = $row[mykey]`, basically

Comment: oncodeeater,  that was a typo in my question.  the real code has correct spelling

Comment: You're not doing anything with this `$stmt->execute();` - `$stmt` is just a stray variable. You're not doing anything with `$stmt1` and `$stmt2` and not executing any of your queries. You need to fetch over a loop for your first query and use that row assignment for the second one; that's what needs to be done here.

Comment: $stmt1 and $stmt2 where for my question only, so I could show you guys the different $stmt is was using.  in the real code they are defined as $stmt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to concatenate `$row['mykey']` to `stmt2` instead of including it directly because it might be interpreted as a string.

It should be like this

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT client_id, companyname, contact, contractor_lock FROM table two WHERE contractor_lock = ?");
$stmt2->execute($row['mykey']);
```

Comment: That shouldn't matter. MySQL will compensate for it.

Comment: kamal, I get the following error when making your change, but rt133813 is the value I'm looking for.  Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rt133813' in 'where clause'

Comment: Plus, `rt133813` is a string here and not an integer as stated by a comment from the OP.

Comment: @RickyT I edited my answer. See it now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- He wrote it as a string in his question.

Comment: Which is exactly that, a string *"Unknown column '`rt133813`' in 'where clause'"*

Comment: rt133813 is the string value in my database I retrieved from table one.  in other words $mykey = "rt133813" and I'm checking to see if $contractor_lock="rt133813" then display all fields in that record.

Comment: I tried $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT client_id, companyname, contact, contractor_lock FROM table two WHERE contractor_lock = ?");
$stmt->execute($row['mykey']);  No errors, but no data either

Comment: @RickyT Did you try executing the query directly in your database server (phpmyadmin or whatever is installed on your machine)?

Comment: Like this but replace = 'rt133813' with = $row['mykey']          $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT client_id, companyname, contact, address, city, state, zip, areacode, phonenumber, contractor_lock FROM ricks_inserts WHERE contractor_lock = 'rt133813'");

Comment: no kamal, I did not, but the last comment above works great, just need to replace 'rt133813' with a variable as when different logins will have different results.

Comment: @RickyT When using values directly in your queries, you should use `quote()` to get the required value interpreted correctly by your database. See here http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php.

Comment: Got it guys,  needed to add   $stmt->bindValue(1, $row['mykey'], PDO::PARAM_STR);  Thanks for all your help!